# How do I order execution of NUnit test fixtures?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have a NUnit test project which has two `[TextFixture]`s.

I want one of them to run before the other as it deals with file creation. They're currently running in the wrong order.

Given that I can't change the `[Test]`s or group them into a single unit test, is there a way in which I can have control over test fixture running order?

I have tried `[Order(int num)]` attribute and have also tried to create a new playlist.

Both of them aren't working.

C#, .NET Framework, NUnit Testing Framework, Windows.

Comment: First you should try to get test isolated from each other so that order get irrelevant. If that is not possible in your eyes show more of the why it can't be. A test should not be the preparation step of a different test.

Comment: You are correct, but for some reason, I can't change much in unit testing. I'm actually trying to run one `[TestFixture]` before another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`[OrderAttribute]`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html) states that ordering for fixtures **applies within the containing namespace**.

Make sure that your fixtures are within the same namespace & that you've applied `[OrderAttribute]` at the *test fixture* level:

```cs
namespace SameNamespace {
    [TestFixture, Order(1)]
    public class MyFirstFixture
    {
        /* ... */ }
    }

    [TestFixture, Order(2)]
    public class MySecondFixture
    {
        /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Also, it's important to remember that while `MyFirstFixture` will run before `MySecondFixture`, the ordering of the tests inside is *local* to the test fixture.

A test with `[Order(1)]` in `MySecondFixture` will run *after* all the tests in `MyFirstFixture` have completed.

---

**Important note: the documentation also does not guarantee ordering.**

> Tests do not wait for prior tests to finish. If multiple threads are in use, a test may be started while some earlier tests are still being run.

---

Regardless, tests should be following the F.I.R.S.T principles of testing, introduced by Robert C. Martin in his book "Clean Code".

The **I** in F.I.R.ST. stands for **isolated**, meaning that tests should not be dependable on one another & each test should be responsible for the setup it requires to be executed correctly.

Try your best to eventually combine the tests into one if they are testing one thing, or rewrite your logic in a way where the piece of code being tested by test 1, can be tested *isolated* from the piece of code being tested by test 2.

This will also have the side effect of cleaner code adhering to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Win-win situation.

Comment: Let's just say for education purposes that I have to keep tests just the way it is, i.e., they are dependent on each other. Given that condition, is there a way to control the execution order. And I have two different test class (`[TestFixture]`)

Comment: Are you trying to control order across multiple fixtures, within the same fixture or order a fixture before another one?

Comment: Order of fixture. I want one fixture to run before another.

Comment: @SahilVerma Updated answer for fixture ordering, if that doesn't work share your test fixture setup & namespaces in the question please.

Comment: Also, note that NUnit ordering can only be used as a __stand-in__ for dependencies, since it is only concerned with the order in which tests are started. In case of parallel execution, two tests with different ordering values may be running at the same time. And even in a non-parallel environment, ordering doesn't require that the first test should succeed. True dependency relations among tests and fixtures would be a major enhancement. It has been discussed but no work has been done AFAIK.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks Charlie, I made that a bit clearer in the answer quoting the documentation. Thanks again!